# Unit testing null inputs at the cost of syntax errors?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing

I've inherited a project with some unit tests validating null inputs even if it was clearly stated in the arguments that they are mandatory.

Below is an example of how the production code went.

```
class Pasta {
  getIngredient(name: string) {
    if(name == null) {
      throw "need input"
    }
    console.log(name)
  }
}

var p = new Pasta()
p.getIngredient("noodles")
p.getIngredient()
```

My primary concern is when doing this in typescript it will clearly state a syntax error because the function getIngredient() needs to have something inputted. I get that comprehensive testing is key but is this even essential? The fact that it raises an error at IDE level means that this shouldn't be done, but that code is tolerating errors for comprehensiveness and if this was Kotlin it wouldn't even have compiled.

I would think that the lines

```
    if(name == null) {
      throw "need input"
    }
```

and its test are not even needed.

If you think it is needed, why so? Thank you.

Comment: Your assessment seems correct - it smells like double-testing. That said, you might want the default null input behavior to be "need input" instead of a generic syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Testing against `null` when it's forbidden by the type system *can* be worth it, but it depends a lot on how the code is used.

If the code is used by clients who might not be type checking their JS (whether via TypeScript, or Flow, or whatever) then null checks can be a useful way to fail-fast and give the client useful feedback.  I suspect this is the reason comparing `null` to `string` is legal, though I'm not 100% on that.  If you control all the potential callers of the code *and* are always type checking inputs (that is you don't have explicit casts, or anys in play) then such `null` checks are fine to remove.

For what it's worth, the same thing comes up in C# with nullable reference types (since only C# 8+ can check those, and most C# is pre-8) and [I subscribe to Jon Skeet's guidance that nullability checks still make sense in C# 8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54538000/80572).